# Jenkinsfile: Trim choice parameters and pass it to stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is the jenkins file i'm using. But now i need to select ID based on ENVIRONMENT as it is not easy to remember account ID based on ENVIRONMENT.
Is there a way i can add in jenkinsfile I can do when i select sdbx to pick 1807402234.  Please suggest

or is there way to trim the ID parameters when it comes to stage if i use choice parameter as below.

```
choice(
    name: 'ID',
    choices: [ 'sdbx-1807402234', 'devl-5187460678', 'test-891137040']
)
```

NOTE: I need both ENVIRONMENT and ID parameters. Also I'm a begginer to jenkins groovy.

My Jenkinsfile

```
def deploy(env) {
  step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
  siteName: siteName,
  deploy: [
  $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
  deployApp: appName,
  deployEnv: 'DEV',
  deployVersions: "${compName}:${version}",
  deployProc: simpleDeploy,
  deployOnlyChanged: false,
  deployReqProps: "ID=${params.ID}"
 ]])

parameters {
  choice(
  name: 'ENVIRONMENT',
  choices: [ 'sdbx', 'devl', 'test' ]
  )

  choice(
    name: 'ID',
    choices: [ '1807402234', '5187460678', '891137040']
)
stage (DEV') {

    steps {
        script {
         if (params.ENVIRONMENT == "dev"){
             deploy('devl') ===> this will call my deploy function
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achive this by using `split`  function.
`PARAMS = params.ID.split("-")`
Example :

```
def PARAMS = []
pipeline {
     parameters
    {
         choice(
                choices: ['sdbx-1807402234', 'devl-5187460678', 'test-891137040'], 
                name: 'ID'
               )
    }
agent any
   stages {
            stage (DEV') {
              steps {
               script{
                   // Split choice parameter selected  ID by '-'
                   PARAMS = params.ID.split("-")
                   // Get environment name selected
                   def environment = PARAMS[0]
                   // Get ID selected
                   def id = PARAMS[1]
                   println ("environment is : ${environment}")
                   println ("id is : ${id}")
                   if (environment  == "dev"){
                          deploy('devl') ===> this will call my deploy function
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
   }
```

**Output :**
[image]
[image]